# I want to convert strings to summarized strings (Motor1986 -> Xx0)

Tags: python, nlp

I want to convert a list of strings to summarized version also called shapes.

Examples:

```
motor -> xx
My -> Xx
Mylyn -> Xx
Chan-yong -> Xx-xx
```

More examples:

```
G.M. -> X.X.
Machine-223 -> Xx-0
```

Comment: Your explanation is not clear. Please elaborate

Comment: I want to put a list of words in a summarized format that preserves the features of the word. So the capital letters are capital letter but the size of the string does not exceed two characters.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I am hoping to find something ready in a library or something before I start implementing it

Comment: What about `it's` and `John's`, should they become `xx'x` and `Xx'x` or something else?

Comment: What about `ACLU`? `DeJong`? `d'Souza`? `InterCapsCorp`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like following and will put it so others may use it

```
def get_pattern(word):
    pattern = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter.isalpha():
            if pattern[-2:].lower() != 'xx':
                if letter.isupper():
                    pattern += 'X'
                elif letter.islower():
                    pattern += 'x'
        elif letter.isdigit():
            if pattern[-1:] != '0':
                pattern += '0'
        else:
            pattern += '.'
    return pattern
```